# Is event independence a function of the probability function?

Tags: probability, independence

I would like your help with understanding whether the concept of independence between two events depend on the chosen probability function that we use.
In other words, I am showing you a discrete experiment with two probabilities distributions associated with it.
I define two events and apply the independence formula to them using both the probabilities.
In one case, the events result independent, in the other, they don't.

Sample space S = $\{1, 2, 3, 4\}$

$\mathcal P = \{\emptyset, \{1\}, \{2\}, \{3\}, \{4\}, \{1,2\}, \{1,3\}, \{1,4\}, \{2,3\}, \{2,4\}, \{3,4\}, \{1,2,3\},$ $\{2,3,4\}, \{1,3,4\},\{1,2,4\},\{1,2,3,4\}\}$

Probability1 $P_1 = \left(\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{4}\right)$ (uniform)

Probability2 $P_2 = \left(\frac{9}{16}, \frac{3}{16}, \frac{3}{16}, \frac{1}{16}\right)$.

I think both the probabilities verify the three axioms that qualify functions as "probability functions".

Now:

Event $A = \{1, 2\}; \, \,$ Event $B = \{1, 4\}$

With P1: $P_1(A)\cdot P_1(B) = \frac12\cdot \frac12 = \frac14$ and $P_1(A \cap B) = P_1({1}) = \frac14$.

$A$ and $B$ are independent

With P2: $P_2(A)\cdot P_2(B) = \frac{12}{16}\cdot \frac{10}{16} = \frac{15}{32}$, $P_2(A \cap B) = P_2({1}) = \frac{9}{16}$.

$A$ and $B$ are **not** independent

Does this prove that independence is a function of the chosen (or assumed) probability?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Yes - in non-degenerate cases, independence between two events depends on their particular joint distribution.  Your example illustrates this for a particular case

Comment: Of course it depends on that! The definition of independent events is $P(A\land B)=P(A)P(B)$; if you change $P$ there's no reason that should be preserved.

Comment: Just a little thing ...don´t you mean $\mathcal{P}=\{\emptyset,\{1\},...\}$?

Comment: Thanks everyone for the feedback. I had to ask this question because no book or resource that I have read stresses this concept.
You are often faced the difference between disjointedness and independence, stating that they are different concept. They are and disjointedness depends only on the events whereas independence depends on the chosen (or assumed) probability too.
Disjointedness involves the union operator whereas independence the intersect operator. So without specifying better the object of this post, a student might think of some sort of "dualism" between them, but is not the case